# Apache/ab testing trouble - apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)

Tags: windows, apache

I have a problem with testing **Apache server 2.4** by **ab**. The Apache server runs on Windows as a service and I test it from another server which is on Linux.

I write:

```
 ab -n 1000 -c 1000 "http://x.x.x.x/image.jpg"
```

Output:

```
 This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
 Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
 Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

 Benchmarking x.x.x.x (be patient)
 apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)
```

When *-n* and *-c* is 100, it is without a problem.
Previously I had tested it a it had been all right but all at once it began to crash.
I tried everything, even **mpm_winnt_module** but it didn't help.

(I use default values in Apache.)

I suppose that is not a network problem. I can see in Wireshark that communication is reseted after a while. According to me Apache is guilty.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, Apache only has `ThreadsPerChild` number of threads and can accept exactly that many number of connections, + `ListenBacklog` threads can be queued by the operating system.

Any more, and the connections will be refused.

Using something as basic as netstat will show you the number of current and queued connections (the latter will show with a non-zero receive queue).

You'll need to scale up `ThreadsPerChild` if you want more concurrent connections. This is the most basic of scaling configuration item for windows.

Comment: Doesn't work. httpd.conf - http://pastebin.com/h8ag1i4G, httpd-mpm.conf - http://pastebin.com/tvvymW6s, error.log - http://pastebin.com/86kBwBbG.

Comment: WireShark log - https://www.dropbox.com/s/5u3n373kq5h2xi1/log.txt. It is for command: ab -n 2000 -c 2000 "http://something.com/logo_inverzni.jpg".

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have multiple interfaces with **ifconfig** or **ip addr**. I used

ab -c 20 -n 1000 **-B 12.34.56.78** http://www.example.com/

which -B is the addres to bind the stress test and 12.34.56.78 is the interface connected to internet.

Comment: I don't get it. The option -B is not available in ab.

Comment: My ab version is  "This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1604373 $>"
Maybe versions older than this one might not have this option. As I checked "$Revision: 655654 $" does not have this option. Try updating apache-tools package.
The -B option is available in the fedora package.
"-B address      Address to bind to when making outgoing connections"